# Laravel sort arrays custom from querybuilder result

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I got a result from a querybuilder and what I want is  want to modify the arrangement of the arrays.

What I first get is this one

```
  {
    "outsourcer": "ＮＳ＆Ｃ㈱",
    "manager_name": "安楽",
    "worker_name": "吉田邦広",
    "sesnum1": "MS-JAN-",
    "sesnum2": 1,
    "start": "2021-10-29",
    "work": "TEST作業１",
    "cost": 765000,
    "worktime_l": "140",
    "worktime_h": "180",
    "cost_add": 1000,
    "cost_trip": "7000",
    "cost_trip_terms": "泊数換算",
    "cost_midnight": 3000,
    "cost_reduced": 0,
    "end_date": "2022-03-31",
    "end": "2022-03-31",
    "quarter": "年度2022 1Q",
    "reserve1": "",
    "reserve2": "",
    "working_period": "6か月"
  },
```

and what I want to do is

```
 {
    "outsourcer": "ＮＳ＆Ｃ㈱",
    "manager_name": "安楽",
    "worker_name": "吉田邦広",
    "sesnum1": "MS-JAN-",
    "sesnum2": 1,
    "start": "2021-10-29",
    "end": "2022-03-31", //transfered
    "work": "TEST作業１",
    "quarter": "年度2022 1Q", //transfered
    "working_period": "6か月" //transfered
    "reserve1": "", //transfered
    "cost": 765000,
    "worktime_l": "140",
    "worktime_h": "180",
    "cost_add": 1000,
    "cost_trip": "7000",
    "cost_trip_terms": "泊数換算",
    "cost_midnight": 3000,
    "cost_reduced": 0,
    "reserve2": "",
    "end_date": "2022-03-31", //transfered
  },
```

How can I achieve it? Do i need a custom function for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry your question is to unclear. transferred from where? are you just mutating data or getting it from another model?, if you are mutating. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators if you are amending it, use map.

Comment: i just want to change the order of the result sir. @MichaelMano

Comment: In that case, why? thats the front ends job. e.g. how you render the data. if you really want to change the order in which its returned use the `toArray` method on the model. return what data and the order you like but this is pointless

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the following two arrays are equivalent:

```php
[
   'key1' => 'value1',
   'key2' => 'value2',
]
```

```php
[
   'key2' => 'value2',
   'key1' => 'value1',
]
```

There is no sort order for arrays keyed by strings.